# Linux Static Driver Loading Issue

Tags: linux

There is some problem in static loading of driver which is leading to confusion.
To load the driver statically I followed two ways Process 1) and Process 2).
Earlier I had followed:

Process 1:
The steps are:

1. I built my char driver named demochardrv.ko.
2. I copied the driver in /lib/modules/2.6.34.12/kernel/drivers/char/.
3. I made an entry of it in /etc/modules.
4. Reboot.

But these 4 steps were not working earlier and I did not see my driver in lsmod.

So apart from the above steps I followed the other way:
Process 2:
The steps are as:

1. I added the driver details in file "/lib/modules/2.6.34.12/build/drivers/char/Kconfig":
   config DEMOCHARDRV
   tristate "TEST DEMO DRIVER'
   default n
   help
   TEST STATIC INSTALL DRIVER
2. I added the driver details in "/lib/modules/2.6.34.12/build/drivers/char/Makefile":
   obj-$(CONFIG_DEMOCHARDRV) += demochardrv.o
3. Copied the driver files in /lib/modules/2.6.34.12/build/drivers/char/.
4. Edited the .config file and added CONFIG_DEMOCHARDRV=y.
5. Fired make menuconfig and selected(with either * / M) my driver.
6. Did make, make modules, make modules_install and make install.
7. Reboot

Now the driver was loading at boot time even if I was not selecting it in menuconfig.

To resolve the issue in Process 2 I removed the entry made in /etc/modules. But now the driver was not loading at all.
So I removed the Process 2 steps and again followed Process 1 steps and driver is loading at boot time now.
Now Process 1 is working.
But Process 2 is not working alone and it need additional steps of Process 1.

So I am confused as to which process are correct.
Can anybody pls provide some inputs?

Comment: I want to load the driver at boot time statically and so I cannot use insmod.

Answer (score 1):

When you're loading Linux driver "statically", you cannot compile is a module, you have to build it right into the kernel binary. Therefore, you should not treat it as module at all, and configure it either as "*" (built-in), or don't include it at all.

According to the [kernel makefile doc](http://www.ravnborg.org/kbuild/makefiles.html), the second process should be the way to go. However, you should give up on the idea of making a module, since module is always loaded dynamically.